# Java 11 installation complains about dependencies

Tags: dpkg, java, openjdk

I have installed Java 11  from this site - https://bell-sw.com/pages/repositories/#apt by using the following commands:

```
wget -q -O - https://download.bell-sw.com/pki/GPG-KEY-bellsoft | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://apt.bell-sw.com/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bellsoft.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bellsoft-java11
```

Currently I get:

"Следующие пакеты имеют неудовлетворённые зависимости:
default-jre-headless : Зависит: openjdk-11-jre-headless но он не будет установлен
E: Неудовлетворённые зависимости. Попытайтесь выполнить «apt --fix-broken install», не указывая имени пакета (или указав решение)."

Tried to use `apt --fix-broken install`

"Подготовка к распаковке …/openjdk-11-jre-headless_11.0.11+9-0ubuntu2~20.04_amd64
.deb …
Распаковывается openjdk-11-jre-headless:amd64 (11.0.11+9-0ubuntu2~20.04) …
dpkg-deb (подпроцесс): разжимающий элемент архива: ошибка lzma:
сжатые данные повреждены
dpkg-deb: ошибка:  subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg:
ошибка при обработке архива /var/cache/apt/archives/openjdk-11-jre-headles
s_11.0.11+9-0ubuntu2~20.04_amd64.deb (--unpack):

не удалось скопировать извлечённые данные «./usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/
lib/modules» в «/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/modules.dpkg-new»:
неожиданный конец файла или потока

При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
/var/cache/apt/archives/openjdk-11-jre-headless_11.0.11+9-0ubuntu2~20.04_amd64.
deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)"

Comment: What was wrong with `default-jre` which is [packaged](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/default-jdk) for Ubuntu at the same 11 version? Why do you install Java from third-party vendor? Please include the output of `grep -ir "^deb" /etc/apt/ --include=*.list`, `apt-cache policy default-jre-headless openjdk-11-jre-headless` and `update-java-alternatives -l` to the question.

Comment: I don't need a JRE, but a JDK. Namely, this version of the JDK is recommended for working with Kubernetes. I switched from Windows to Linux, I hoped that there would be less problems with Docker

Comment: You may want to convert the messages to English not much help here otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You have broken download. To fix it open terminal and run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get clean

sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```